# odoo 10 domain check_in date != check_out date

Tags: list, odoo-10

I'm working with attendances and I want to get a list of attendances where the check_in.date() != check_out.date()  is there a way to do this with a search(domain)?

Comment: Anyone have an idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer I came up with.

```
    attendances = self.env['hr.attendance'].search([('tz_check_out', '!=', False)]).filtered(lambda r: datetime.strptime(r.tz_check_in, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT).date() != datetime.strptime(r.tz_check_out, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT).date())
    attendances |= self.env['hr.attendance'].search([('tz_check_out', '=', False), ('tz_check_in', '!=', False)]).filtered(lambda r: datetime.strptime(r.tz_check_in, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT).date() != date.today())
```

using the filtered() method instead of putting the date comparisons in the search() method allows for me to compare fields within a record instead of a field against an outside value.